# How can I left align text in a TextButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

I am trying to left-align 'Add attachment' in the TextButton so it lines up with 'Starts' and 'Ends'.

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  width: 350,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
  child: TextButton(
    child: const Align(
      child: Text(
      'Add attachment...',
      style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue, fontSize: 16),
      textAlign: TextAlign.left
        ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
  )
),
```

I have tried adding `textAlign: TextAlign.left` to the TextButton but it is not working. I suspect the TextButton is not taking up the entire width of the Container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this:

[image]

```
TextButton(
// if you are not set the alignment, by default it will align center
    child: const Align( 
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Text('Add attachment...',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left),
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
```

also you can use aligmnet from container. the result willbe  same

```
  Container(
  height: 50,
  width: 350,
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
  child: TextButton(
    child: Text('Add attachment...',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 16),
        textAlign: TextAlign.left),
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

in container add   `alignment: Alignment.centerleft,`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can remove the text-align and replace it with your text widget and then add alignment: Alignment. center-left to your container, and for the press function, you can wrap the container with GestureDetector widget.

So the code will be as follows:

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){},
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 350,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: Text(
            'Add attachment...',
            style: TextStyle(color: CupertinoColors.activeBlue, fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```